# Hibernate Exception: Could not parse mapping document

Tags: java, hibernate

I use netbeans 6.7.1 to write "hello world" with hibernate, but I get some errors, please help me, thank you very much.

**my exception**

[[Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate/Tbluser.hbm.xml]]

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Copying 1 file to F:\Documents and Settings\My Dropbox\DropboxNetBeanProjects\loginspring\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
compile-single:
run-main:
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: Reading mappings from resource : hibernate/Tbluser.hbm.xml
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:06 AM org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
SEVERE: Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(1) Document is invalid: no grammar found.
Oct 25, 2009 2:44:06 AM org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper$ErrorLogger error
SEVERE: Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(1) Document root element "hibernate-mapping", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate/Tbluser.hbm.xml
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1587)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
        at hibernate.CreateTest.main(CreateTest.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:502)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
        ... 8 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Tbluser.hbm.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 25, 2009 2:37:30 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.Tbluser" table="tbluser" catalog="hibernate">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="userID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="string">
            <column name="phone" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="groupId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="groupID" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Tbluser.java**

```
  package hibernate;
// Generated Oct 25, 2009 2:37:30 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA



    /**
     * Tbluser generated by hbm2java
     */
    public class Tbluser  implements java.io.Serializable {


         private Integer userId;
         private String username;
         private String password;
         private String email;
         private String phone;
         private Integer groupId;

        public Tbluser() {
        }

        public Tbluser(String username, String password, String email, String phone, Integer groupId) {
           this.username = username;
           this.password = password;
           this.email = email;
           this.phone = phone;
           this.groupId = groupId;
        }

        public Integer getUserId() {
            return this.userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return this.username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getPhone() {
            return this.phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
        public Integer getGroupId() {
            return this.groupId;
        }

        public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
            this.groupId = groupId;
        }


}
```

Comment: Tbluser.hbm.xml starts with a space try remove that

Comment: how do the columns of the table in the database look like? maybe they have a different case and cant be mapped so you would have to specify them too in your hbm.xml file. And why do you write java.lang.Integer? Do you need this? You can just write int

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate configuration file you missed out the mapping element for your hbm file.you should define like  in your hibernate.cfg.xml..

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to add a mapping for your Tbluser.hbm.xml in your hibernate cfg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

  <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="Tbluser.hbm.xml"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the xml parser is trying to access the schema or dtd mentioned in the configuration file and fails to succeed.

Make sure your application has access to http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd or get the document from there put it somewhere where your application can access it add change the path in the document accordingly

Comment: I got .dtd file and add to my project, but exceptions did not appear. :(

Comment: `exceptions did not appear` so your issue got resolved or not?